# Milky Way Density Profile

Tags: density, data, milky-way

Does anyone know where I can find either a printed version or, better, a downloadable dump of data giving me the density profile of the Milky Way?  I'm looking to put together a quick-and-dirty simulation of the Milky Way and the bulge data is very important for looking at the velocity profiles.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80837

Comment: Googling "Phil Plait" and "Emily Lakdawalla" may get you going. They both have great astronomy blogs.

Comment: So is it the density profile you need, or would a description of the potential suffice?

Comment: I'm looking for either a chart (or formula) which describes the way the density of matter (stars, ISM) changes as a function of the distance from the galactic center.  I'm not sure to what 'potential' you are referring.

Comment: @DRAirey1 The gravitational potential (including dark matter). You mention stars and ISM, but these contribute the minority of the density of the Milky Way. What are you trying to simulate?

Comment: I am just looking for a reasonable proxy for the Milky Way for testing out a model I have that produces flat velocity curves without Dark Matter.  So I'm looking for the baryonic mass of the Milky Way (bulge and disk) and some modern data that gives, simply, distance from the center, velocity and dispersion.  Any direction you have to real data would be welcome.

Comment: Are you dead set on the MW, or would you settle for a galaxy with better measurements?

Comment: The Milky Way has much better velocity data for which to do the model testing.  Unfortunately, you can't see the trees for the forest and it's difficult to get luminosity/mass profiles in our own back yard.  I found some good data on Andromeda from Corbelli et al (2009) and Chemin et al (2009).  Do you have something better?