# Galactic Rotation Curve Calculation

Tags: dark-matter, galaxy-rotation-curve

Can anyone give the list of formulas used for plotting the Galactic Rotation Curves? I mean, is there only the formula for linear velocity or is the formula for the gravitational potential also involved? Also, is there a paper where the  corresponding calculations and actual data are mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68955/25301, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80837/25301